# Dynatrace api/v2/metrics response missing Metric Latency

Tags: dynatrace

I have a requirement where I need to know the latency of every metric and based on that I can write the logic to get the metrics. I went through the document and found **api/v2/metrics** provides the metric latency in the response as per the doc https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/dynatrace-api/environment-api/metric-v2/get-all-metrics but somehow this is missing in the response.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you post you exact command? You need to specify the field "latency" in parameter "fields" to include it in the response.

Comment: curl -L -X GET 'https://dtenv.live.dynatrace.com/api/v2/metrics?fields=unit,latency&metricSelector=builtin:*' -H 'Authorization: Api-Token api-token' -H 'Accept: application/json'


This only includes unit with the metricId

Comment: It seems that only few metrics have a latency set out of the box, e.g. builtin:cloud.vmware.hypervisor.availability returns a latency of "10". For "custom" metrics you can specify the latency in the metric metadata settings  which are available via the "Metrics" page in the UI.